# How can I fail Maven build if exec:java goal fails?

Tags: maven-2

We're using the Maven `exec:java` goal to run a custom java application that configures a database for use with our integration tests. We want to use `exec:java` over `exec:exec` to be able to use the project dependencies in the classpath of the main class to be used.
A few times the application has failed for valid reasons, but the Maven build continued as if nothing had gone wrong.

Is there any "failonerror" type argument that can be used with `exec:java`? I'm afraid to add `system.exit()` codes to the class being run, as I suspect it will kill not only itself, but also Maven itself, due to the fact it's running in the Maven VM.

Comment: is it possible to use exec:exec, in that case i guess you can use return codes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just did a simple test with the following plugin configuration declared in a POM:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>my-exec-java</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
</project>
```

And the following Java class:

```
package com.example;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        throw new RuntimeException("A problem occured");
    }
}
```

And this is what I get when invoking the `integration-test` phase:

```
$ mvn clean integration-test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building q2363055
[INFO]    task-segment: [clean, integration-test]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

...

[INFO] [jar:jar {execution: default-jar}]
[INFO] Building jar: /home/pascal/Projects/stackoverflow/q2363055/target/q2363055-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Preparing exec:java
[WARNING] Removing: java from forked lifecycle, to prevent recursive invocation.
[INFO] No goals needed for project - skipping
[INFO] [exec:java {execution: my-exec-java}]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] An exception occured while executing the Java class. null

A problem occured
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 19 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Mar 02 23:40:32 CET 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/79M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The `integration` phase is never executed, because of the build error.

So the question is, how are you handling errors in the Java class that loads your db? Is throwing an exception an option?

Comment: Thanks Pascal. I've had an opportunity to look at the source and see a lot of unhandled errors. I believe your solution would work if the class being called had better exception handling. Thanks for the comprehensive answer!

Comment: Thanks! I had the same problem starting HSQLDB. An exception was thrown and not displayed. I was getting the same error above!. I was passing invalid <argument>s to hsqldb..........

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a feature it has by default, but you might want to request it at http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MEXEC, as it would be a simple addition.

If you want `exec:java` to fail the build, the `main` call will need to throw an exception instead of returning a non-zero exit code.

If that's not an option, you can still use `exec:exec` - see http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-for-java-programs.html for a description on how to add the project dependencies to the classpath.

A further option if neither of these suit for some reason is to use the AntRun plugin with the `<java .../>` task. Project dependencies can also be passed into that.

Comment: Thanks Brett, I ended up using the antrun plugin in the end.

Comment: I'm trying to use exec:exec with a java main because I need to control the exit code and when it gets to the System.exit(-1) it kills the build even when it is supposed to be run in a child process. what to do?

Answer (score 1):

For java goal `System.exit(n)`, where `n` is non-zero will not work. Need to throw java exception.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to throwing an exception, you can also use `System.exit(n)`, where n is non-zero to cause the maven build to fail.

Comment: The downside here is that for the `java` goal it kills the host Maven JVM too